# How is this different from defining a variable type?

Tags: java

Someone on another answer posted the code:

```
List<ISpeak> animalsThatTalk = new ArrayList<ISpeak>();
```

What does the <> do?

**Update**

I know my 2nd example wouldn't compile... I've rephrased my question due to the confusion.

Comment: That second example doesn't even come close to compiling.

Comment: What? I don't understand what you're trying to do with the parenthesis.

Comment: Huh? I don't get the syntax in the second example. You sure you didn't mean `List<Speak> animalsThatTalk = new ArrayList<ISpeak>();`?

Comment: I'd suggest to look again on *that other* answer and correct this question.

Comment: @OscarRyz I think @Webnet question is about the different in parenthesis. He is new to Java, probably just learn about it less than a week.

Comment: I know the 2nd one won't begin to compile, it was merely an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angle brackets, i.e. `<...>`, are used for type parameters. You must supply a type, e.g. `Integer` or `String`. Round parentheses are used for value parameters, and you must supply a value e.g. 1 or "Hello World".

Example:

```
new ArrayList<String>(3)
```

This defines a new list of strings with initial capacity 3. `String` is the type parameter. `3` is a value parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your question is on the use of <> vs ().  Collections typically require you to specify a parameter or type for the collection.  <> is used to do this.

So in your example, a List of type ISpeak is being created

```
List<ISpeak>
```

You could also create a list of integers

```
List<Integer>
```

The <> simply allows you to define the type of object that the collection will contain.

The second example

```
List (Speak) animalsThatTalk
```

Won't compile.  The compiler will try to call the function List with an argument of Speak.

Comment: The second one won't compile in Java either. You're a C# programmer?

Comment: Indeed, fixed for my Java friends.

Comment: So if say just for this example `List` is an array, then `List<Integer>` would define the values in that array as integers?

Comment: If you want to create a List full of integers called myList then List<Integer> myList would define the values of myList as type Integer.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the syntax of the language... the second one is just not valid in Java, although it would almost compile in a language like D. That's just how they decided it, it's not really right or wrong. They decided to put the type arguments in carets because they're not variables, so they're not like normal arguments.